# Applications of the natural bilinear forms on the direct sum between a vector space and its dual

Tags: linear-algebra, clifford-algebras, big-list

As is known, the vector space $V\oplus V^\ast$ admits the natural symmetric and skew-symmetric bilinear forms
$$\langle X+\xi,Y+\eta\rangle|_\pm:=\frac 1 2 (\xi(Y) \pm \eta(X)).$$

I am interested in collecting results concerning these bilinear forms and their  applications. They were used for example in

- [Lie groups as spin groups (Doran, Hestenes, Sommen, and Van Acker)](http://www.mrao.cam.ac.uk/~clifford/publications/abstracts/lie_groups.html),
- and in [Generalized Calabi–Yau manifolds (Hitchin)](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.dg/0209099) and [Generalized complex geometry (Gualtieri)](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703298v2)

Comment: Both these forms are indefinite (trace zero), so perhaps they should not be called inner products in the title?

Comment: This is a local version of a global result, namely that cotangent bundles are symplectic manifolds, and this gets used in mathematical physics. 

Answer (score 2):

Search for Dirac structures or Courant algebroids in MathSciNet:
These are common generalizations of symplectic and Poisson structures and use the symmetric bilinear form on $TM\times_M T^*M$ on a manifold: Namely, the graph of a symplectic structure as well as the graph of a Poisson structure are maximal isotropic subbundles, with further properties.

There is a lot of literature on them now.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, Dirac structures are also mentioned in the works on Generalized complex geometry.